# wxpython close app when run sqlite3 commands

Tags: python, sqlite, wxpython

I'm trying to make a program with SQLite3 in python 3.7. The interface is with WxPython 4.0.3 and then I compile it with Nuitka 0.6.0. In other projects WxPython compiled in Nuitka works well. But at the moment I try to start a database with SQLite the program closes automatically.

After seeing what could happen, I started the code by right clicking and "open with python" in the root file of the program. And it closes automatically too. But if in the file folder I open CMD and run the file with "python app.py" the program works well.

Here I leave the simplified script. If you simply delete the line with `self.db = sqlite3.connect("database.db")` and then open the code with right click and open with python the program opens and works well. But the moment you leave the line to make the connection with SQLite, it stops working. I do not understand where to get it and when I search in google I get results that have nothing to do with this.

the code:

```
import wx
import sqlite3

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(None, id=wx.ID_ANY, title="PDF database",
                                      pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.Size(500, 300),
                                      style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)

        self.db = sqlite3.connect("database.db")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    main_window = MyFrame()
    main_window.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while of research, I found a solution.

The problem with this is where python starts when right-clicking and "open with python". If you have a script that is simply:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
input("whatever")
```

If you open that script by opening cmd and moving with cd to the folder with "this_code.py". You'll see that the terminal prints the directory of the folder you're in. But if you right click and "open with python" in the terminal prints the path to System32. Also you will need the input to freeze the terminal waiting for the user to press enter because if you do not include "input", the terminal is closed before you can see the directory (or the error printed across a try-except).

So when I have SQLite. When opening the file with right click and open with python. SQLite tries to find or create "database.db" in System32 folder. And there is a permission problem. To solve this and to can open the file no matter how or where. Simply add:

```
import os
script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

script_dir will be the location of the file and not the place from which it was called Python. So, when you open a connection to SQLite. Use `sqlite3.connect(f'file:{script_dir}/database.db', uri=True)`

And this will always have the same correct behavior, no matter how you open it or where you call it from.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something here, but it looks like if you do a standalone install using Nuitka, it excludes sqlite which may be causing the issue. See Nuitka's changelog under the Optimization heading here:

- http://nuitka.net/doc/Changelog.pdf

I know I have been able to use sqlite and wxPython when using py2exe and PyInstaller.

Comment: It doesn't exactly concern Niutka. Niutka was the "exhibitor" of the error. But then, I tried different ways to start the python code, the pre-compilling one. And if I right click on "app.py" and "open with Python" (interpreted with CPython) the error is the same. I went to ask in some places and found the solution. I will put that in a proper answer to mark it as accepted. (anyway, thanks for the pdf, it helped me on other issues).